# How to get the link to the selected symbol? (TradingView widget)

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I try to use this advanced widget by TradingView: https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/.

Maybe I miss something obvious, but how can I get the link to the selected symbol? For example, I click on the "Symbol Search" area (upper-left corner of the chart) and select TSLA. Now, how can I get the link to the selected ticker, ie. https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-TSLA/?

Is there any possible way to get this value, maybe by Javascript? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, in pinescript you can bind a ticker through security(tickerid) function... not sure if this helps out.

Comment: Anything may help, it's strange why this simple and useful thing is not available yet, but I hope it can be resolved, it is useful for all who actually use this or similar widget.. thank you.